# Redirect debug output of Chromium in Python

Tags: python, chromium, qtwebengine, pywebview

I have a pywebview, that launches a Qt window utilizing the QtWebEngine with Chromium on Windows.

When starting the webview in debug mode, the following output is of particular interest for me:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:8228/devtools/browser/<GUID>
```

This line is output by the Chromium engine itself and I want to make the debug port and GUID available in my application. For that, my idea is to redirect all terminal outputs to a `StringIO` stream.

Here is a minimum example of what I have done so far, to redirect all outputs:

```py
from contextlib import redirect_stdout, redirect_stderr
from io import StringIO
import logging

from PyQt5 import QtCore
import webview

def qt_message_handler(mode, context, message):
    # Redirect message to stdout
    print(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Let the handler redirect all qt messages to stdout
    QtCore.qInstallMessageHandler(qt_message_handler)
    stream = StringIO()
    # Redirect stdout and stderr to stream
    with redirect_stdout(stream), redirect_stderr(stream):
        # Redirect all loging outputs to stream
        stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream)
        loggers = [logging.getLogger(name) for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict]
        for logger in loggers:
            for handler in logger.handlers:
                logger.removeHandler(handler)
            logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
        # Start the webview window
        window = webview.create_window('Webview window')
        webview.start(gui='qt', debug=True)
```

Ths approach redirects all outputs to the stream object as intended **except** the one line output by Chromium mentioned at the beginning.

So i played around with the `QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS` environment variable. Since `pywebview` overrides this environment variable, I changed it directly in the `pywebview` module. However no argument passed to Chromium by this environment variable seems to change the output behaviour of this specific line. Looking at the Chromium source code, this makes sense:

```cpp
std::string message = base::StringPrintf(
    "\nDevTools listening on ws://%s%s\n", ip_address->ToString().c_str(),
    browser_guid.c_str());
fprintf(stderr, "%s", message.c_str());
fflush(stderr);
```

Since the message is directly printed to `stderr` no Chromium logging flags have an influence. But it's clearly evident, that the message gets printed to `stderr`, so why does a redirect of `stderr` in Python have no effect on this message? Is there any way to redirect this message in python?

#### Bonus question:

A further look into the Chromium source code shows, that the debug port and GUID are also written into a file:

```cpp
if (!output_directory.empty()) {
  base::FilePath path =
      output_directory.Append(kDevToolsActivePortFileName);
  std::string port_target_string = base::StringPrintf(
      "%d\n%s", ip_address->port(), browser_guid.c_str());
  if (base::WriteFile(path, port_target_string.c_str(),
                      static_cast<int>(port_target_string.length())) < 0) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "Error writing DevTools active port to file";
  }
}
```

I just can't figure out where Chromium stores this data. Where can this file be located on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some findings that, while not directly answering the question, do lead to a conclusion:

1. Why is the `stderr` of Chromium not redirected? This is because Chromium is launched in a child process by the QtWebEngine. While it would be possible, to get the output of a child process in Python, it would require to mess around with the QtWebEngine. At this point I decided, that this is not worth the effort.
2. Regarding my bonus question, I found out that the file containting the debug port and GUID should be named `DevToolsActivePort`. However, this file is not created when using the QtWebEngine and I haven't found out yet, why this is the case. See this question for a possible answer in the future: [QtWebEngine: DevToolsActivePort file is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72917526/qtwebengine-devtoolsactiveport-file-is-missing)
3. How did I solve my issue? I found out, that a query exists which returns the websocket url among other things: `http://<debug_server_url>/json/version` ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59394164/4028761)). While you can determine the debug port within the QtWebEngine, I solved it for my pywebview application similar to this:

```py
import requests
from PySide6 import QtCore
import webview

debug_server_url = None

def qt_message_handler(mode, context, message):
    # Check if the message is the one containing the debug server url
    if message.startswith('Remote debugging server started successfully.'):
        # Debug server url is at the end of the message
        global debug_server_url
        debug_server_url = message.split()[-1]

def on_loaded():
    if debug_server_url is not None:
        websocket_debugger_url = requests.get(debug_server_url + '/json/version').json()['webSocketDebuggerUrl']
        print(websocket_debugger_url)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Define a custom qt message handler
    QtCore.qInstallMessageHandler(qt_message_handler)
    window = webview.create_window('Webview window')
    window.events.loaded += on_loaded
    webview.start(gui='qt', debug=True)
```